# SharePoint Modern - Can a Calculated Text field be appended to an item title using JSON?

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

I am customizing a Sharepoint Modern list form using JSON.  The list has a field titled 'RequestID'. I would like to customize the header to include this value.  I have added this field to the form, except that it is hidden using conditional formatting.

I have tried this:

```
                "txtContent": "='Application Change Request Form - ' + [$RequestID]"
```

It is not working all it shows:
**Application Change Request Form - **

It does not show the calculated field.

Here is the entire code I am using:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "16px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "Group",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "height": "36px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "='Application Change Request Form - ' + [$RequestID]"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please tell me what I have done wrong.

Tammy

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this from my end and I am able to reproduce this issue. I think this is a bug while using calculated column in JSON form formatting.

The calculated column value is available in the page context but it is not shown in form header:

[image]

I have raised a new bug/issue here: [JSON Form formatting: Unable to use the calculated column value in header/footer layout customization](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8788). Hopefully Microsoft will fix this in near future.

**Similar thread**: [How to get value of Calculated field in Header using JSON?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306408/how-to-get-value-of-calculated-field-in-header-using-json/306439#306439)